# Rewriting pure functions

Tags: functions

Can anyone help me to obtain the identical output using a pure function with less code?

```
list = {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 9}, {13, 5, 6}};
f1[x_] := {Max /@ x, Last /@ x }
f1[list]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty readable as-is. Is this homework?

Comment: What about `{Max /@ #, Last /@ #} &`?